# passing string argument to onclick javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, string, function, onclick

I am trying to pass a javascript variable to an onclick function, the function works fine with number variables but not with strings.  I need to pass the attribut from an object like so:

```
onclick="showImg(<%= ep.trackId%>);
```

My showImg function accepts this attribut, but when I try passing a string like so:

```
onclick='showImg(\""+<%= ep.artworkUrl30 %>+"\");'>
```

The function simply doesn't work. Is there a way to make it work or bypass this problem?

Comment: try my updated answer here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33578023/3057648

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to pollute html with function calls, so do not use onclick attribute. Use javaScript to add an event listener.

```
var someString = "\<%= ep.artworkUrl30 %>\";
element.addEventListener('click', function(someString){
   //do something with someString
});
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener

Answer (score 1):

The ASP.NET code nuggets (`<%=` ... `%>`) are processed on the server side; no need to concatenate the quote marks. Try simply:

```
onclick='showImg("<%= ep.artworkUrl30 %>");'>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the `'` are not closed properly  please try

```
onclick='showImg(\"'+<%= ep.artworkUrl30 %>+'\");'>
```

**EDIT :**
after viewing your code
  you can try

```
<% var epArray = episodes[0]; %>
<% _.each(epArray, function(ep){ %>
    <option value="<%= ep.trackNumber %>" onclick='showImg("<%= ep.artworkUrl30 %>");'><%= ep.trackName %></option>
<% }); %>
```

Answer (score 0):

Its definitely a problem with how you are escaping the various quotes. It really depends what the context of your statement is. If you are in raw HTML then you should have:

```
    <body onclick='showImg("<%= ep.artworkUrl30 %>")'></body>
```

If you need quotes within your string then these would be:

```
    <body onclick='showImg("\"<%= ep.artworkUrl30 %>\"")'></body>
```

However if you are trying to generate HTML within javascript (like it appears you might be) then you may have to use other string escaping methods.